# How to duplicate each row using shell comands?

Tags: shell-script

I have a bunch of data as below.

```
1,A9600,001_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime    
2,A9600,002_DEP,NA,TIME,startTime
3,A9600,003_LIT,NA,TIME,startTime
4,A9600,004_ETC,NA,TIME,startTime
5,B9600,005_CMP,NA,TIME,startTime
6,B9600,006_IMP,NA,TIME,startTime
7,B9600,007_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime
```

and I want them to be modified as below.

```
1,A9600,001_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime
1,A9600_1,001_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime
1,A9600_2,001_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime
1,A9600_3,001_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime  
2,A9600,002_DEP,NA,TIME,startTime
2,A9600_1,002_DEP,NA,TIME,startTime
2,A9600_2,002_DEP,NA,TIME,startTime
2,A9600_3,002_DEP,NA,TIME,startTime
....
```

How to achieve this using shell commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple awk loop

```
awk -v num=3 'BEGIN {OFS=FS=","} 
  {tmp=$2; print; for (i=1;i<=num;i++) {$2=tmp"_"i; print}}
  ' file
```

Adjust `num` as desired.

Answer (score 0):

So essentually, you want to repeat each line four times with different suffixes after the second field?

```
sed 'p;s/,/_1,/2p;s/_1/_2/p;s/_2/_3/' file
```

This is `p` to print the line as is; the first `s` command adds `_1` before the second comma and prints; the second and third `s` replaces with `_2` and `_3`, the second wears the `p` flag to print the line, while the last version is printed by default.

**Edit after expanded question**

If you want to loop for a given number of iterations, you can do

```
sed 'p;s/,/_1,/2p;G;s/$/0123456789+/;:a
s/\(_[0-9]*\)\([0-9]\)\(,.*\n.*\2\)\(.\)/\1\4\3\4/
s/_+/_10/;s/\(_[0-9]*\)\([0-9]\)+\(.*\n.*\2\)\(.\)/\1\40\3\2\4/
/_+/!P
/_123,/! ta
d' file
```

where `123` in the next-to-last line is the maximum index. At the moment I have not the time to explain, but I can do that later if you want to understand what is happening.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to add the new lines using loop. Because I want to expand them as much as I could. (not only just 3 rows.)

Comment: So you have a variable with the maximum suffix or what?

Comment: If I add 100 rows for each row, I need to type from one to a hundred to achieve my goal. However, it is very time consuming. So I would more appreciate it if you could change your solutions by using for loops.

Comment: I understood that. I just want to know how to get the maximum of the loop

Comment: Maybe 50 will be enough for me

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pse '$l = $_;
   for my $k ( 1 .. $N ) { s/\z/$l =~ s|^[^,]+,[^,]+\K|_$k|r/e }
' -- -N=3 -- Input.data
```

---

### Working

- `-p` option sets up an implict file read in loop + autoprint of records.
- `-s` allows variables to be set from command lines, in our case `$N`. YMMV.
- Save the present record into $l.
- We loop and append into the current record the contents of $l modified at the location where the 2nd comma is found.